# Proof of the independence of the sample mean and sample variance

Tags: statistics

I've been trying to establish that the sample
mean and the sample variance are independent. One motivation is to
try and write the sample variance, $S^{2}$ as a function
of $\left\{ X_{2}-\bar{X},X_{3}-\bar{X},\cdots,X_{n}-\bar{X}\right\} =A$
only. Then we proceed by showing that $A$ and $\bar{X}$ are independent (**which I'm unable to show**),
which then implies the independence of $S^{2}$ and $\bar{X}.$

I would appreciate it if the good people of M.SE would help guide me in the right direction.
Thanks.

**Edit:**
The random samples $X_1,\cdots,X_n$ are from an $N(\mu, \sigma)$ distribution.

Comment: No, $A$ and $\bar X$ are not independent in general. Since you seem to be following a book or some lecture notes, you might want to check these again.

Comment: I have edited...:)

Comment: Do you know how to check if $(A,\bar{X})$ are jointly Gaussian in your case? The other method is to verify independence using characteristic function.

Comment: @Gortaur:No, I do not. Could please show me how? thanks.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I guess this is probably a little late, but this result is immediate from [Basu's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basu%27s_theorem), provided that you are willing to accept that the family of normal distributions with known variance is complete. To apply Basu, fix $\sigma^2$ and consider the family of $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ for $\mu \in \mathbb R$. Then $\frac{(n - 1)S^2}{\sigma^2} \sim \chi^2_{n - 1}$ so $S^2$ is ancillary, while $\bar X$ is complete sufficient, and hence they are independent for all $\mu$ and our fixed $\sigma^2$. Since $\sigma^2$ was arbitrary, this completes the proof.

This can also be shown directly without too much hassle. One can find the joint pdf of $(A, \bar X)$ directly by making a suitable transformation to the joint pdf of $(X_1,\cdots, X_n)$. The joint pdf of $(A, \bar X)$ factors as required, which gives independence. To see this quickly, without actually doing the transformation, skipping some algebra we may write

$$f(x_1, x_2, ..., x_n) = (2\pi \sigma^2)^{-n/2} \exp\left\{-\frac{\sum(x_i - \bar x)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right\} \exp\left\{-\frac{n(\bar x - \mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right\}$$

and we can see that everything except for the last term depends only on 
$$(x_2 - \bar x, x_3 - \bar x, ..., x_n - \bar x)$$ 
(note we may retrieve $x_1 - \bar x$ from only the first $n - 1$ deviations) and the last term depends only on $\bar x$. The transformation is linear, so the jacobian term won't screw this factorization up when we actually pass to the joint pdf of $(A, \bar X)$.

Comment: +1. (Made some minor typographic edits, hope you do not mind.)

Comment: Don't mind at all. I always use \\[ to get inline equations and was grumpy that I had to use \displaystyle to get what I wanted on this site, so your edit makes me happy; I didn't know about $$ :) I think I accidentally figured out how to it using braces while typing up this comment too.

Comment: @guy: No its never late. Thanks for your nice answer. I wasn't aware of Basu's theorem at that time...:)

Comment: This answer requires knowledge of Basu's theorem, but you certainly don't need that in order to prove this result.

Answer (score 9):

Hint:

1. Show that  $A' = (\bar X, A)$ can be writen as $A' = C X$  where $C$ is some square matrix. Deduce from that that $A'$ is jointly gaussian.
2. Recall that independence is equivalent to zero correlation for jointly gaussian variables.  Show that $E(A_i  \bar X) = 0$. Conclude that $A$ and $\bar X$ are independent.

Comment: I think there is an extra comma sitting in that expectation in (2). Maybe it was originally a covariance that got changed to an expectation since $E(A_i \bar X) = Cov(A_i, \bar X)$? I prefer calculating the covariance, myself.

Comment: Fixed. That's the same as the covariance, yes, because $E(A_i)=0$

Comment: @leonbloy: Thanks for your response.

Comment: @leonbloy This is maybe a little bit too late, but why does the independence of $A$ and $\bar{X}$ imply that $S^2$ and $\bar{X}$ are independent?

Comment: @leonbloy  what is the form of $C$ . I have tried a lot but my efforts were futile !

Answer (score 7):

Here is an alternative matrix approach. By replacing each $X_i$ by $(X_i - \mu)/\sigma$, we can assume wlog that the $X$'s are independent standard normal variables.

Pack $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ into an $n\times 1$ column vector $X$. The idea is to express $\sum X$ and $(X_1-\bar X,\ldots,X_n-\bar X)^T$ as matrix transformations of $X$. This is achieved by taking $U=(1,\ldots,1)$, a $1\times n$ row vector of ones (so that $UX=\sum X_i$), and defining the $n\times n$ matrix
$$C:=I_n - \frac1n U^TU$$
(so that $CX$ has $i$th member $X_i-\bar X$). Check that $UX$ and $CX$ each have zero mean. Their covariance is
$$E[(UX)(CX)^T]=E(UXX^TC^T)=UC^T=UC=U-\frac1nUU^TU.$$
But $UU^T=n$, so the covariance matrix is zero. Since $UX$ are $CX$ are jointly normal, this implies that they are independent, hence so are $\bar X$ and $S^2$, which are functions respectively of $UX$ and $CX$.

---

Why are $UX$ and $CX$ jointly normal? The product of a partitioned matrix with $X$:
$$\begin{pmatrix}U\\\hdashline C\end{pmatrix}X
$$ yields a $(n+1)\times 1$ multivariate normal vector; $UX$ is the first member, and $CX$ is the remaining subvector.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Cochran's theorem for a sample of size n from a Standard Normal. Then show that the sum of degrees of freedom of the two is n. They should equal $n-1$ and $1$.