# Determine the smallest possible sample size

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, self-learning

$Y_1,...,Y_k$ be a sample of size n for each $Y_i$ ~N(m,$s^2$ ) normal distribution for each $i= \{1,...,k\}$ and $m$ and $s^2$ are unknown parameters.

let $m_l= \bar{Y_k}$ and $s_l^2=1/k \sum_{i=1}^k(Y_i-\bar{Y_k})^2$

And let

$P(|m_l - m|\le s/5 \ \ \  \text{and}  \ \ \ |s_l- s |\le s/5 ) \ge 1/2$

Determine the smallest possible sample size k in order that this above probability holds.

Answer (score 1):

Since [sample mean and sample variance are independent for normal r.v.'s](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/47350/proof-of-the-independence-of-the-sample-mean-and-sample-variance), we have that
$$\mathbb P(|m_l - m|\le s/5 \, , |s_l- s |\le s/5 ) =\mathbb P(|m_l - m|\le s/5 )\times\mathbb P( |s_l- s |\le s/5 ) $$
Furthermore, by Chebyshev's inequality, we have
$$\begin{align}\mathbb P(|m_l - m|\le s/5 ) &= 1-\mathbb P(|m_l - m|\ge s/5 )\\
&\ge1-\frac{25\mathrm{Var}(m_l)}{s^2}\\
&= 1 - \frac{25}{n}\end{align} $$
and
$$\begin{align}\mathbb P(|s_l - s|\le s/5 ) &= 1-\mathbb P(|s_l - s|\ge s/5 )\\
&\ge1-\frac{25\mathrm{Var}(s_l)}{s^2}\\
&= 1 - \frac{25}{s^2}\frac{(n-1)(n-3)s^2}{n^3}\\
&= 1 - \frac{25(n-1)(n-3)}{n^3}\end{align} $$
(See [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SampleVarianceDistribution.html) for a derivation of the variance of $s_l$).

Thus, to find $n$ such that $\mathbb P(|m_l - m|\le s/5 \, , |s_l- s |\le s/5 ) \ge 1/2 $, it suffices to find $n$ such that
$$\left(1 - \frac{25}{n}\right)\times\left(1 - \frac{25(n-1)(n-3)}{n^3}\right) \ge \frac{1}{2} $$
Also note that this will most likely not give you the smallest $n$ such that the inequality holds, as Chebyshev's inequality tends to give quite loose bounds. If you want something better, you might need to look at some results from [large deviations theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_deviations_theory) which can give much better (exponential) bounds.