# if i have random sample from standard normal then prove indepenednt of $\bar Z$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n (Z_i - \bar Z)^2$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, normal-distribution, independence, parametric

If $ Z_1 , Z_2 , .. , Z_n $ is a random sample from a standard normal distibution , then:

$\bar Z$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n (Z_i - \bar Z)^2$ are independent

Comment: How did you approach this problem, Karim ?

Comment: @Hamdiken I got MGF of $\bar Z$ but I can't see how to get MGF for second half or both of them since i know if i want to prove indepnent i have to prove MGF of AB equals MGF A * MGF B

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/47350/321264

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is equal to a basic property of the sample mean and variance from the normal distribution. That is
$$ \overline{X} \text{ and } S^2 \text{ are independent random varables}$$
They can be proven as follow, without MGF.
Before that, we have to list **two important theorems**

> 1. Let $X_1,...X_n$ be random vectors. Then they are *mutually independent random vectors if and only if* we have $g_i(x_i)$ such that the joint pdf of $(X_1,...X_n)$ can be written as $f(x_1,...x_n)=\prod g_i(x_i)$
> 2. Let $X_1,...X_n$ be *independent random vectors* and $g_i(x_i)$ be a function only of $x_i$. Then we have $U_i=g_i(X_i)$ are *mutually independent* as well.

Firstly, note
$$
\begin{aligned}
S^2 &= \frac{1}{(n-1)}\sum_{i=1}^{n}({X_i-\overline{X}})^2 \\
&= \frac{1}{(n-1)}\left((X_1-\overline{X})^2+\sum_{i=2}^{n}({X_i-\overline{X}})^2\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{(n-1)}\left(\left[\sum_{i=2}^{n}(X_i-\overline{X})\right]^2+\sum_{i=2}^{n}({X_i-\overline{X}})^2\right)
\text{ since } 
\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_i-\overline{X})=0
\end{aligned} 
$$
Hence, we constructed $S^2$ as a function of $(X_2-\overline{X},...,X_n-\overline{X})$. We want to show that these variables are independent of $\overline{X}$.

Then, the joint pdf of $X_1,...,X_n$ can be given by
$$
f(x_1,...x_n)=\prod f_i(x_i)=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2}}e^{-(1/2)\sum{x_i^2}},\quad -\infty < x_i <  \infty
$$
Make a multivariate transformations as follow
$$
\begin{aligned}
y_1 &= \overline{x},\\
y_2 &= x_2-\overline{x},\\
\cdots\\
y_n &= x_n-\overline{x}
\end{aligned}
$$
which is a linear transformation with a Jacobian of $1/n$. So we have 
$f(y_1,...y_n) $
$$
\large = \frac{n}{(2\pi)^{n/2}}e^ {-\left(1/2\right)(y_ {1}-\sum _ {2}^ {n}y_ {i})^ {2}}  e^ {-(1/2)\sum _ {2}^ {n}(y_ {i}+y_ {1})^ {2}}, \infty  <  y_ {i}  <  \infty \\
\large = \left[(\frac{n}{2\pi})^{1/2}e^ {\left(-n y_1^2 \right)/2 }\right]
\left[ \frac{n^{1/2}}{(2\pi)^{(n-1)/2}}e^ {-\left(1/2\right)[\sum_2^{n}y_i^2 + (\sum_2^n{y_i})^2]}  \right], \infty  <  y_ {i}  <  \infty
$$
Since we find that the joint pdf of $Y_1,...,Y_n$ can factors as $g_i(y_i)$. According to theorem 1, we have $Y_1$ is independent of the others.
Furthermore, regarding theorem 2, we can get $\overline{X}$ is independent to $S^2$

> Basically from *Statistical Inference* of Casella, G. & Berger, R. L.